# Trouble in changing button color on every click

Tags: android

I'm new to Android app.. I was trying to change the button color on first click and to change back to default on the next click and this will work no matter how many times user clicks...
Can anyone help me to understand this

Answer (score 0):

Create global variable clickStatus

```
boolean clickStatus=true;

final Button running_app=(Button)findViewById(R.id.running_app);
running_app.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickStatus){
                    clickStatus=false;
                    running_app.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
                }else {
                    clickStatus=true;
                    running_app.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                }
            }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your view.. I will look forward to apply it

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Just give two different tags to button and keep toggling it on button click. That would help you to change background colour alternatively. Here is the complete code for it. Hope this helps.

Here is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Click Me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnClick.setTag("1");
        btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getTag().equals("1")) {
            view.setTag("0");
            btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else  {
            view.setTag("1");
            btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you give this code a try ? It's working code.